# Magento 2: How to reload Order Summary Section?

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, orders, magento2.2.2

I have some custom discount applied through custom ajax after ajax completion, I want to reload Order summary section on checkout page.

> mysite.com/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information

After debugging I observe that The above link when called the Order Summary section reloads but, How to reload it with my custom ajax request ?

**=> section.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">

<action name="http://127.0.0.1/grocebee_dev/loadSummary">
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
</action>
```

ajax request

```
// baseurl return 'http://127.0.0.1/grocebee_dev'
    var newUrl = baseUrl+'/loadSummary';

                                $.ajax({
                                    type : 'post',
                                    url : newUrl,
                                    success:function(newData)
                                    {
                                        console.log(newData);
                                    }
                                });
```

But it shows 404 error

Comment: what is your frontname for routes.xml of your module?

Comment: frontname="referralcredit"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use 'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals' to update the order summary .

Please check this code

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
    'ko',

], function (Component, $, getTotalsAction, ko) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        validatevat:function(){
            var newUrl = baseUrl+'/loadSummary';
            $.ajax({
                url: newUrl,

                data:  {
                },
                type: "post",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    var deferred = $.Deferred();
                    getTotalsAction([], deferred); //this will reload the order summary section I have used it in my custom module 
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Try this but give an error in console 'TypeError: getTotalsAction is not a function' http://prntscr.com/p7k9ed

Comment: @ChiragGondaliya can you please add your js code

Comment: Don't forget to define 'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals', as getTotalsAction

Answer (score 3):

You can reload it with section.

Create sections.xml in your module etc/frontend/ folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">

<action name="your/url/here">
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
</action>
```

Second option is through js

```
require(['jquery','Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function ($,customerData) {
        var sections = ['checkout-data'];
        customerData.invalidate(sections);
        customerData.reload(sections, true);

 });
```

Comment: What to put in 'your/url/here'

Comment: It is your ajax request url.

Comment: I updated my question please review

Comment: @BunnyXudot `<action name="grocebee_dev/loadSummary/index">` use this dear.

Comment: I have use it like <action name="frontname/controllerfolder/index"> and it's look like <action name="referralcredit/customer/index"> and it returns 200 now but section did not loads

Comment: @BunnyXudot try with js method

Comment: where to put this js.
Let me clear i have a checkbox on checkout page from which i want to reload order summary section when checkbox checked So what I have to do Sir

Comment: @BunnyXudot where you sending ajax request

Comment: first i have send request to my conroller name ajax where it can update some colunms in my custom table after success i want to reload order summary section

Comment: @BunnyXudot add code on ajax success

Comment: After adding your js code it did not works

Comment: @BunnyXudot update code here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75493/discussion-between-bunny-xudot-and-qaisar-satti).

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep below section in your sections.xml file,

```
<action name="referralcredit/loadsummary/index">
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
</action>
```

Comment: it returns 200 status now but Order Summary section did not reload

Comment: check my update you have to keep loadsummary instead of customer

Comment: but there is no folder like loadSummary in my controller so it will give me 404

Comment: whats your actuall action url?

Comment: Let me clear i have a checkbox on checkout page from which i want to reload order summary section when checkbox checked So what I have to do Sir.

Comment: but your action url give me for this action?

Comment: I have no url just review the ans no 1

Comment: Have you checked

Answer (score 0):

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default',
], function (Component, $, quote, ko, totalsDefaultProvider) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        updateTaxValue:function(){
            //Start Custom Changes//
                quote.shippingMethod.subscribe(function () {
                    console.log("1");
                    totalsDefaultProvider.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
                });

                quote.billingAddress.subscribe(function () {
                    var type = quote.billingAddress().getType();
                    if (quote.isVirtual()) {
                        // update totals block when estimated address was set
                        totalsProcessors['default'] = totalsDefaultProvider;
                        totalsProcessors[type] ?
                            totalsProcessors[type].estimateTotals(quote.billingAddress()) :
                            totalsProcessors['default'].estimateTotals(quote.billingAddress());
                    }
                });
            //End Custom Changes//
        }
    });
});
```